# Elasticsearch, index new document only if unique (two fields make a unique index)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document like this one:

```
{
    "transactionId": "F8B416F6A1414C0AA77D2F7377BD6455siP1",
    "timestamp": "2020-09-01T09:45:10.924Z"
}
```

these two fields make this document unique.
I want to make sure that when trying to store another document having same values on both fields I get an error- it is not possible.

How can I do it?

BTW- I am using `"elasticsearch": "15.4.0",` client.

Thank you :-)

Comment: So you're saying it's possible to have two documents with the exact same transactionId at different times? If not, why not use the `transactionId` as document ID?

Comment: It is possible that the same document (with the same transactionId and timestamp) will be  added to ElasticSearch (and I want to make it impossible).

Comment: What I'm asking is whether it makes sense to have two different documents with the same transactionId but a different timestamp?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

### Deduplication with a Consistent Hash

This won't actually refuse to create the document, but it will overwrite the existing document. So you'll never have two documents in Elasticsearch with the same timestamp and transactionId.

```rb
# in the filter section, create a consistent hash of
# timestamp and transactionID fields
filter {
  fingerprint {
    source => [ "transactionId", "timestamp" ]
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
    concatenate_sources => true
  }
}

# in the elasticsearch output, use that hash as document ID
output {
  elasticsearch {
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
  }
}
```

This should be useful if *either* of the following conditions are true:

- All documents with the same `timestamp` and `transactionId` are completely identical; and/or
- You don't mind whether the first or last version is indexed.

Conversely, it won't work if *both* of these are true:

- Some documents with the same timestamp and transactionId are different; and
- It's important to you to only use the first document

(I personally use this approach a lot, to facilitate "at least once" delivery)

### Actually Prevent Overwrite

To actually prevent overwriting of existing documents, you need to do all of the above *plus* use security controls. Check the [Indices privileges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/security-privileges.html#privileges-list-indices) docs for the `create_doc` privilege:

> Privilege to index new documents, without allowing overwriting or updating existing ones.

The user writing to the index should have `create_doc` privilege and none of `all`, `create`, `delete`, `index` or `write`.

This approach will do exactly what you asked for. It's important to still use a consistent hash of the input fields as `document_id` so that security controls can do their thing.

(I personally haven't done this, so there might be some gotchas not discussed here)